# Pesquisa de dados com DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Estou trabalhando com WinForms e estou tentando implementar um `DataGridView(dgv)` em um formulário de pesquisa que tenho em meu projeto.

O que acontece é: Tenho dois dgvs que formam a espécie de um mestre-detalhe. Eu o fiz seguindo [esse tutorial](https://programandodotnet.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/exibicao-mestre-detalhe-de-registros-parte-1/). Do jeito que ta no tuto, fiz algumas adaptações e tudo funcionou na boa, ele me retorna os dados do banco e tal.

Mas preciso ir um pouco além. Preciso que além do dgv mostrar os dados do banco, quero também fazer com que ao clicar em uma linha ele carregue esses dados em um form de cadastro para que eu possa editar esses dados. Sei que se eu fizer em `ListView` vai funcionar, mas quero aprender também a usar o dgv.

E mais, tenho um textbox de pesquisa e dois radiobuttons, que são os critérios de pesquisa do `textbox`, e mais um botão. Ou seja, escolho o criterio nos `radiobuttons`(código ou nome) e coloco o valor no textbox e ao apertar o botão, ele faça a pesquisa no banco e me retorne em um dgv... Mas essa parte da pesquisa não funciona e nem o doubleclick na linha, me retornando um erro de que o indice não pode ser negativo.

Enfim será que alguém pode me ajudar ? Seja um link de um tutorial ou com códigos de exemplo ?

Os códigos que tenho são:

```
public partial class frmPesquisaAluno : Form
{
    //decalramos a variável publica do tipo string
    public string sCdCodigo;
    public string sDsNome;

    public frmPesquisaAluno()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CarregarDados();
        //inicializamos a variável como vazia
        sCdCodigo = string.Empty;
        sDsNome = string.Empty;
    }

    private void frmPesquisaAluno_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public DataViewManager dvManager;

    public void CarregarDados()
    {
        string strConexao = @"Data Source=ServidorBD;Initial Catalog=BD;Integrated Security=True;

        using (SqlConnection objConexao = new SqlConnection(strConexao))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("AlunosOcorrencia");

            SqlDataAdapter daCustomers = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Alunoes", objConexao);
            daCustomers.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Alunoes");
            daCustomers.Fill(ds);

            SqlDataAdapter daOrders = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Ocorrencias", objConexao);
            daOrders.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Ocorrencias");
            daOrders.Fill(ds);

            DataRelation relCustOrder;
            DataColumn colMaster1;
            DataColumn colDetail1;
            colMaster1 = ds.Tables["Alunoes"].Columns["AlunoID"];
            colDetail1 = ds.Tables["Ocorrencias"].Columns["AlunoID"];
            relCustOrder = new DataRelation("AlunoCorrencias", colMaster1, colDetail1);
            ds.Relations.Add(relCustOrder);

            dvManager = ds.DefaultViewManager;

            dataGridViewAlunos.DataSource = dvManager;
            dataGridViewAlunos.DataMember = "Alunoes";

            dataGridViewOcorrencias.DataSource = dvManager;
            dataGridViewOcorrencias.DataMember = "Alunoes.AlunoCorrencias";
        }
    }

    private void dataGridViewAlunos_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            sCdCodigo = dataGridViewAlunos.SelectedRows[0].ToString();
            sDsNome = dataGridViewAlunos.SelectedRows[0].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    private void dataGridViewAlunos_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            sCdCodigo = dataGridViewAlunos.SelectedRows[0].ToString();
            sDsNome = dataGridViewAlunos.SelectedRows[0].ToString();
            Close();
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    public virtual void Pesquisar()
    {

    }

    private void buttonPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //chamo o método de pesquisa
        Pesquisar();            
    }

    private void radioButtonCodigo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //quando o usuário clicar no RadioButton, o foco é 
        //automaticamente setado para o TextBox de pesquisa
        textBoxPesquisar.Focus();
    }

    private void radioButtonDescricao_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //quando o usuário clicar no RadioButton, o foco é 
        //automaticamente setado para o TextBox de pesquisa
        textBoxPesquisar.Focus();
    }       
}
```

Esse é o código completo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Érik
O que está acontecendo é que vc não está passando o valor correto para a tabela seguinte onde contenha os dados que serão exibidos no detalhes.

No caso a tabela Ocorrencias tem que ter um item de busca para o aluno selecionado, a sua busca irá ficar assim :

```
SqlDataAdapter daOrders = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Ocorrencias WHERE idAlunao=@idAlunao", objConexao);
```

Confira a sintaxe!
Indique o parametro na pesquisa, assim poderá detalhar as ocorrências do item da tabela Alunoes.
Para vc controlar melhor os dados que utiliza nas pesquisas, procure colocar os campos que irá utilizar, assim você melhora a sua consulta.